# Separate two words in the same colum in awk cli?

Tags: awk, split, grep, command-line-interface, command-line-arguments

In CLI I type:

`$ timedatectl | grep Time | awk '{print $3}'`

Which gives me the correct output:

`Country/City`

How can I just get the print out of city without the Country?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this command instead:

```
timedatectl | grep Time | awk '{print $3}' | cut -d/ -f2
```

Comment: I will in 10 mins when it lets me :)